# Prototype: Get the type of a selected element?

Tags: prototypejs

Lets say, I select an element using Prototype like this:

```
var elem = $$('.someclass')[0];
```

Is there a way to figure out, what type (li or a or div) this element is?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: I found the solution myself, its elem.tagName.

Comment: You should make that an answer and accept it. That's encouraged here.